# Creating a child class based on external settings

Tags: class, oop, c++11, inheritance

I think my question is related to *object slicing*.

I have the following classes:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual int do_Something();
}

class ChildA : public Base {
public:
    int do_Something();    // ChildA does something
}

class ChildB : public Base {
public:
    int do_Something();    // ChildB does something
}
```

In my `main.cpp` I want to create an object ChildA() or ChildB() based on a specific configuration that the user sets. 
As an example, a (very ugly) way I can imagine is:

```
int config = 1; // selected by the user

Base *base;
if (config==0){
    ChildA child = (ChildA)base;
}
else if (config==1){
    ChildB child = (ChildB)base;
}

child->doSomething();
```

Does this make sense and what is a better way to do this?

Comment: C++ is not Java; thus unless you ask for it, you don't have a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From different answers, I found that a sensible way to do this would be:

```
int config = 1; // selected by the user

Base *base;
if (config==0){
    base = new ChildA();
}
else if (config==1){
    base = new ChildB();
}
```